# add the names to file1 based on file2

Tags: awk

I have two files file1 and file2. some of the names in file2 are not in file1. I would like to add that names in file1.

file1

```
anna         14/2   =   7.0
alex         23/6   =   3.8
deffy        27/3   =   9.0
hobert       24/9   =   2.7
```

file2

```
anna
alex
benny
cathar
deffy
hobbert
sam
```

My desired output is shown below.

```
anna         14/2   =   7.0
alex         23/6   =   3.8
benny        0/0    =   0
cathar       0/0    =   0 
deffy        27/3   =   9.0
hobert       24/9   =   2.7
sam          0/0    =   0
```

your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}a[$0]{print a[$0];next}{print $1,"0/0 = 0"} ' f1 f2|column -t
anna     14/2  =  7.0
alex     23/6  =  3.8
benny    0/0   =  0
cathar   0/0   =  0
deffy    27/3  =  9.0
hobbert  0/0   =  0
sam      0/0   =  0
```

Comment: As a nix tinkerer, may I ask for a bit more breakdown of this script. I just do not get what a[$0] is doing. An array but it doesn't seem to be populated. Obviously, next step is to set this up and run it and tinker a bit. But any additional tips would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk`,

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next} {$0=($1 in a )?a[$1]:$0" 0/0 = 0"}1' file1 file2
```